# How to add Faker data type to SDV model (update metadata)

Tags: python, faker, sdv

I'm trying to add Faker data type to SDV model.

Imports:

```
from sdv.metadata import SingleTableMetadata
from sdv.single_table import GaussianCopulaSynthesizer
import faker
```

Code:

```
fake = faker.Faker()

metadata = SingleTableMetadata()
metadata.detect_from_dataframe(data=df)

metadata.update_column(
    column_name='DR_Prod',
    sdtype='fake.company'
)
```

I also tryied to add: 'faker.providers.company', but every time gets error  (kernel crash).

After metadata.detect i run this code:

```
synthesizer = GaussianCopulaSynthesizer(metadata)
synthesizer.fit(df)
synthetic_data = synthesizer.sample(num_rows=len(df))
```

I can run code without metadata.update, but I don't get result, that I need.

sdv.**version** '1.2.0'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure out, how to solve this problem.
There's updated code:

```
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker
from sdv.metadata import SingleTableMetadata
from sdv.single_table import GaussianCopulaSynthesizer

# fuction for generation fake first name
fake = Faker(['en_GB'])

# making fake list
names_list = []

for _ in range(5):
    names_list.append(
        fake.first_name()
    )

# making dataframe with fake names
df = pd.DataFrame(data=names_list)
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'Names'}).reset_index()

# get matadata from df
metadata = SingleTableMetadata()
metadata.detect_from_dataframe(data=df)

# this fuctions is using to generate first names in synthetic dataframe
Faker.seed(0)

# update metadata
# just add faker.provider:
# it can be: 'company', 'first_name' or 'job'
metadata.update_column(
    column_name='Names',
    sdtype='first_name'
)

# create model with launguage needed (check localized providers on faker site)
synthesizer = GaussianCopulaSynthesizer(metadata, locales=['en_GB'])

# model fit
synthesizer.fit(df)
# generate fake dataframe
synthetic_data = synthesizer.sample(num_rows=len(df))
```

There's outputs( df and synthetic_data):

|  | index | Names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Emily |
| 1 | 1 | Simon |
| 2 | 2 | Garry |
| 3 | 3 | Denise |
| 4 | 4 | Danielle |

|  | index | Names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Aaron |
| 1 | 3 | Gillian |
| 2 | 1 | Sheila |
| 3 | 2 | Julia |
| 4 | 1 | Caroline |

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you to get some insights

1. Add the Faker data type to the model.

   `model.add_field(name="name", type="faker.name")`

change `sdtype` to `type`

2. Update the metadata for the model.

   `model = sdv.SDV()`

   `model.add_field(name="name", type="faker.name")`

   `model.update_metadata()`

   `data = model.generate_data(10)`

   `for row in data:`
   `print(row["name"])`

Comment: I don't get it. This 'sdv.create_model' don't work. And I can't found this command at SDV site.

Comment: yeah, I checked again and it is not valid yet. you can use `sdv.SDV()` instead